# How does copyright on Recipes work?

Tags: copyright

Say there's website X that features a bunch of recipes authored by themselves. The recipes feature

Afaik you can't have copyright on a recipe, only on the imagery and textual description of how to prepare the recipe.

Say I scrape all these recipes and their data (nutrition, ingredients, etc) and use it in my app to do calculations. Based on these calculations I display a link to my users to the page that contains the recipe on website X.

1. Would this be legal?
2. And what if I use their image and recipe title, still linking to website X's recipe.
3. And what if I generate revenue with my app.

Comment: This answer on another SE site may help: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/73908/how-illegal-is-it-to-get-data-from-a-100-accessible-but-not-exposed-api/73913#73913 While you are not using an exposed API, most of this still applies and can be useful.

Comment: In addition to the link supplied by closetnoc, I'll also note my concern that the specific selection and ordering of the recipes could be a "compilation" under U.S. law: the creative decision-making in compiling the set of recipes might satisfy copyright's "modicum of creativity" requirement. See [17 USC §103](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/103): "*The copyright in such [compilation] is independent of [...] any copyright protection in the preexisting material.*" I'm not 100% sure about that, though. There may be relevant case law; I don't know.

Comment: @closetnoc It's an interesting writeup, but I have a hard time mapping it to my case. I see some similarities, but for some points I fail to see if my case is the same or the opposite.

I feel like in my case, regardless of the law, the party that provides the recipes benefits from me. However when money comes into play it becomes tricky perhaps.

Comment: @apsillers so the concern you describe is actually something that could benefit me? Since I'm making a "compilation" I could be independent of the possible copyright protection on the recipes.

Comment: The larger point is you do not have the right to the material regardless of how you think it benefits anyone. For example, I steal your motorcycle and sell it for far more than it is worth. I take a small percentage and give you the rest, still far more than the motorcycle is worth. I will still be arrested for theft. The API story is exactly the same. Open API or scraping, it does not matter.

Comment: @closetnoc No it's not. I would _copy_ your motorcycle, sell it for a profit and cut you in. I guess you wouldn't say no to that. However I see your point. Howhowever this was not my original question. Is the only copyrighted part I would use the recipe's image?

Comment: Except that you have no right to copy anything copyrighted at all regardless of your intent. That is the point that you are missing. You have no idea what the content owner might like or not. You do not have the right to find out by doing. You will have to get permission first.

Comment: Not for the list of ingredients